# How to build an inplace edit with dart angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-dart

I'm very impressed by the angularjs example that writes directly to a div (without having to hide/show an )

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms (**section Implementing custom form controls (using ngModel)**)

```
    angular.module('form-example2', []).directive('contenteditable', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$render = function() {
      elm.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
    };
}});
```

I actually don't understand who intercepts the keyup event to put it into the $viewValue and write it back to the div, so I'm unable to reproduce this feature in dart angular.

Can anybody explain what's happening behind the scene for that div with the directive? How would AngularDart code for this look like?

Comment: Removed angular-dart tag.  This is angularjs, which is now a separate project and has slightly different strategies.

Comment: do you have any Dart example with the problem?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I want to do the same thing in dart-angular, I'm not interested in the angularjs project, I work with dart

Comment: @rkj the dart example is what I want to receive as an answer :)), so no I don't have a dart example

Comment: Could you attach correct plunker link?

Comment: I edited the question (sorry, I didn't check where the link falls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own directive and tune the interactions and update calls exactly as you like. (Choose how to deal with blur, keyup, keydown event etc.) Here's how I did it. It's a basic example how to build custom directive with two-way binding with Angular 2 and Dart (AngularDart).

**contenteditable.dart**

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';

@Directive(
  selector: '[contentEditable]', //Selector that you'll use in your templates
)
class ContentEditable implements OnChanges {
  Element _el; //holding element's properties and content

  @Input()
  String contentEditableModel;

  @Output()
  EventEmitter contentEditableModelChange = new EventEmitter();

  //Constructor
  ContentEditable(ElementRef ref) {
    _el = ref.nativeElement;
  }

  //This method is called on blur event (can be also 'keyup', 'keydown' etc.)
  @HostListener('blur')
  void onBlur() {
    contentEditableModelChange.emit(_el.text);
  }

  //This implementation updates the editable elements content
  //when model is updated somewhere else
  @override
  ngOnChanges(Map<String, SimpleChange> changes) {
    changes.forEach((String propName, SimpleChange change) {
      _el.innerHtml = change.currentValue;
    });
  }
}
```

And here's how to use the directive (that you just created) in your component...

**my_component.dart**

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2_components/angular2_components.dart';

import 'contenteditable.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-component',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'my_component.html',
  directives: const [ContentEditable],
)

class MyComponent {
  String some_var = "Hello editable!";
}
```

**my_component.html**

```
<div contentEditable [(contentEditableModel)]="some_var">Some text that's overridden by some_var</div>
<h1>Here you see the value updating: {{some_var}}</h1>
And from here you can update it too: <input [(ngModel)]="some_var">
```

Answer (score 1):

The `contenteditable` is a html5 property that allows you to edit anything, nothing related to angular itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Setting and reading the values is handled by ngModel directive, you can use the same in AngularDart - I haven't tried it, but I assume it should work. If it doesn't they you probably need to listen manually to change events (or even better send a patch to ngModel).